# ec2 shared www folder

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Hopfully this question has not been asked before, although i have searched and found nothing slong the lines as this...

First of all, My problem: I have 2 EC2 linux instances running behind an elastic Load Balencer. its working well! very happy with it.

My problems start when it comes to placing/updating the application code on the servers. at the moment, i am litrally, modifying the code on my local machine. zipping it up, uploading it to my personal host, and then Wget'ing down onto the each ec2 instance and unzipping..

Is there an easier way of doing this? Am i able to create some kind of shared folder that will span both instances?

In short: what is the easist way of updating my WWW root on 2 servers?

Many Thanks,

Tom.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** The one way of addressing this problem is using a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) which can transfer your files with `rsync` and build the project on the servers, this is not just yet.

There are quite a bunch of plugins available (PHPUnit, Code Coverage, Code Analysis, etc):

[Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins)

How:

1. [Install Jenkins](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449305352/chapter-first-steps.html)
2. Configure your project (probably you code should be in some code-version-system) with Jenkins

   1. Configure the servers, project-path, pre-job, post-job, etc.
3. Schedule the work/job.
4. That's it, done.

Reference:

1. Configuration:

   1. [configuring - ex.1](http://wiki.mxunit.org/display/default/Continuous+Integration+--+Getting+Started)
   2. [Initial configuration](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449305352/chapter-configuration.html)

      1. [Configuring the jobs](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449305352/chapter-configuration.html)
2. http://agile.dzone.com/news/continuous-integration-php

**2.** You need a code-version-control, it helps you maintain a stable code & have them delivered equally in all environments.

There are two major version system available one is [Git](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) & [Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.intro.whatis.html)

**What can be done (for your situation):**

1. Create a repository
2. Create a project inside the repository
3. Dump all of your code into this project by `svn add <files>` & `svn commit .`
4. Login into your EC2 machine.
5. Run `svn checkout <repository-url-to-project>` which will fetch the code on the machine.

if you have updates/changes to any file, then:

1. You might commit (add) some changes to your repository.
2. Run `svn update <modified-or-newly-created-file-path>` in the machine where you have your code checked-out from repository.

Follow these steps in any other EC2 machine.

**Cheatsheet**

GIT - http://help.github.com/git-cheat-sheets/
SVN - http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/misc/svn01/

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool such as [Puppet](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet) to maintain your server configurations.

Comment: Im slightly confused still.. Won't that solution to maintain my server configurations only provide me with a way of setting the WWW root? (so i can set it! but where do i set it to?"

do i create some sort of EBS and share that across both servers?

can't seem to find any posts on this.. how would the big companys replicate application code across all its web servers?

Tom.

Comment: They put their data and configuration on the Puppet master, and let Puppet handle distributing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@tornup
```

this is a more viable solution. if you're not familiar with `Jenkins` or `Puppet` you can do this following:

go to `bitbucket.com` and start a repository

create a repository there

push your local source code to that repository with sourcetree

from both your machines, do a `git pull` (follow bitbucket instructions)

after that, modify your local code, do multiple commits to test it

then go to both your servers and issue git pull

```
........................................ bitbucket.repo/your main source
...........local...server1.server2 share the same source as bitbucket repo
```

push from local to the bitbucket repo

Once you've graduated from this setup, try `puppet` or `jenkins*` -- puppet is more for standing up servers.